# How to call a predicate inside a loop in prolog?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am trying to the find the sum of a list of predicates, I have defined function that would find the sum for a list of numbers, however I am struggling to make calls to the predicate to return the number value.

For example the following predicates have been defined

```
money(jack,600).
money(amanda,1200).

list_sum([],0).
list_sum([Head|Tail], TotalSum):-
    list_sum(Tail, Sum1),
    TotalSum is temp+Sum1.
```

The list_sum function currently only finds the sum of a list of integers.

How can I make it find the sum of a list of predicates was given `list_sum([jack, amanda], TotalSum)`

Answer (score 0):

Query for the amount of money the person has, and add that to the running total:

```
money(jack,600).
money(amanda,1200).

list_sum([], 0).
list_sum([Person|Tail], TotalSum):-
    money(Person, Amount),              % <-- head of list is a person
    list_sum(Tail, TailSum),
    TotalSum is Amount+TailSum.         % <-- add their money Amount
```